# Expected ')' before string, STD:: not fixing

Tags: c++

In an .h file, I have the following code.

```
#ifndef COUNTEDLOCATIONS
#define COUNTEDLOCATIONS

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
struct CountedLocations {
CountedLocations();
CountedLocations(std::string url, int counter);
std::string url;
int count;
//below is code for a later portion of the project
bool operator== (const CountedLocations&) const;
bool operator< (const CountedLocations&) const;
};
```

In my .cpp file that includes the .h file, my code is

```
#include "countedLocs.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
CountedLocations(std::string url, int counter)
{

}
```

I get the error "Expected ')' before 'url'. I've tried commenting out the empty constructor in the .h file, I've tried messing with semicolons, I've tried removing the std:: that prefixes the 'string url', but nothing seems to work. I tried looking at a similar problem on StackOverflow, but all three of the solutions do nothing. How can I fix this?

EDIT: Originally, I had

```
CountedLocations::CountedLocations(std::string url, int counter)
```

instead of

```
CountedLocations(std::string url, int counter)
```

But that gave me the error "Extra qualification 'CountedLocations::' on member 'CountedLocations' [-fpermissive], so I elected not to use it.

Comment: "I get the error "Expected ')' before 'url'."... and the source file and line number that comes with that error is...? Did you include `<string>` in your *header* ? Also this: `CountedLocations(std::string url, int counter)` should be this: `CountedLocations::CountedLocations(std::string url, int counter)` in your .cpp file.

Comment: Should you define this as : CountedLocations::CountedLocations in cpp?

Comment: @NedStark: That's an answer (it's what's causing this error, the `#include` problem would produce a different error), put it in the answer section.

Comment: "Electing not to use it" isn't the solution. If your header declares that class and the compiler complains that `CountedLocations::CountedLocations` isn't valid, then your not including the file you think you are. Also, your header has no closing fencepost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cpp file (not your header file), you should have this:

```
CountedLocations::CountedLocations(std::string url, int counter)
{

}
```

not this:

```
CountedLocations(std::string url, int counter)
{

}
```

> But that gave me the error "Extra qualification 'CountedLocations::'
>   on member 'CountedLocations' [-fpermissive], so I elected not to use
>   it.

That's the error you would get if you put the qualification on the declaration of the constructor in your class body.

Answer (score 2):

Move need the `#include <string>` from the .cpp to the .h file so that the file `countedLocs.h` knows about `std::string` definition. In your case with one cpp you can switch the order of includes but it would be better to have it in the header there (countedLocs.h) if you plan to use it in other places also.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "countedLocs.h"
```

Comment: It wouldn't just be better in the header, it would be *correct*.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include ALL my code because a lot of it is for something later down the road for the assignment, I do have #includes for <iostream> and <string>, absolutely. Along with #ifndef and #define for COUNTEDLOCATIONS

Comment: @JoJoBya then update your question with *real* source that exhibits the problem please. And since your posted source will no-doubt be different than your actual, *please* mark the line in-source that the compiler is complaining about with an inline comment: `// this is where the error reports.` etc.

Answer (score 2):

If this is really all of your code then you don't have a definition of std::string (ie #include ) before your struct is defined.

.h files should be able to be compiled all by themselves.  put #include  in the .h file (and some include guards too!)